# How to write man page for both Github display and conversion to real man page

Tags: github, markdown, indentation, manpage, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to write a man page in markdown so it displays correctly on Github, but can also be converted to a real man page.

To convert it, I use `pandoc`. It mostly works fine, except for the "options" part.

If I write normal markdown like this:

```markdown
# OPTIONS

**-h**

: Display help

**-v**

: Verbose

**-o**, **\--other**

: Some other option with a much longer description
spanning several lines
```

it works fine to make a real man page with

```
pandoc mytest.1.md -s -t man -o mytest.1
```

But on Github, the md file is displayed with the descriptions starting with ": " and not indented. And in fact, I just realized it's the same here on SO:

> ## OPTIONS
>
> **-h**
>
> : Display help
>
> **-v**
>
> : Verbose
>
> **-o**, **--other**
>
> : Some other option with a much longer description spanning several
> lines

How can I write a man page in Markdown that displays correctly on Github, with indenting and can also be converted to a real man page?